# Strange Top Padding on my second AppBar Flutter

Tags: flutter

[Screen of the strange top padding of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHTXU.png)

I have made two classes : the first has a first AppBar and calls the second one that has also a sticky AppBar and display a list of scrollable Items. However, I have a strange top padding in the second AppBar. I have tried a lot of stuff but nothing seems to work.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(0, _currentAccount),
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize:
                  Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topRight,
                            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF894c56),
                          Color(0xFFa80d0d)
                        ])),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 5),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Votre évenement ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey),
                                  )),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 5),
                                child: Text(
                                  event,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
                                ),
                              )
                            ])),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: ListPrestat('Traiteur', _currentAccount)
            // ListPrestat('Traiteur', _currentAccount)

            ));
  }
```

This is the code of my first class that calls the ListPrestat class here under :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height   ,
       //   -(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6 + 56),
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 50,
            expandedHeight: 0,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFDCDCDC),
            pinned: true,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Color(0xFFDC3535),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen(_currentAccount)),
                );
              },
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            shadowColor: Colors.black,
            elevation: 10,
            bottom: const PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
                child: TagList(ListCat: 'brouette')),
            title: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4),
                child: Text(
                  _currentCat,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 110.0,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
                  CustomListItem2(
                    thumbnail: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          child: Image.network(
                            growableList[index],
                            width: 100.0,
                            height: 100.0,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                          aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                        )),
                    title: 'Chez Luigi',
                    subtitle: 'Les meilleurs pizza hors d\'italie.',
                    ListCat: 'Food Truck',
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Do you have any idea what can have caused this padding and how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your secound class with scaffold

```
Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,),
              ...................
        )
```

Comment: It didn't change anything.